# Plotting engine

Tags: c++, plot

in the C/C++ Area i don't know a light weighted and nice looking library for creating graphs.
I am interested in creating a C++ library with the "gnuplot" functionality as a long term project - first with drawing lines :) .

For this reason i am interested in Papers, keywords, structure and so on where to take look at.

In the first step it would be enough to create one image format like *Jpeg or PNG, EPS* **without using a window** to draw on.

Hopefully i will get information’s where to look :)

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this lib. it's Ch/C++ : https://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/plot/

Ploting is as simple as

```
  #include <math.h>
    #include <chplot.h>
    int main() {
        int numpoints = 36;
        array double x[numpoints], y[numpoints];
        class CPlot plot;

        lindata(0, 360, x, 36);
        y = sin(x*M_PI/180);
        plotxy(x, y, "Ch plot", "xlabel", "ylabel", &plot);

        /* create a postscript file */
        plot.outputType(PLOT_OUTPUTTYPE_FILE, "postscript eps", "demo.eps");
        plot.plotting();

        /* create a png file */
        plot.outputType(PLOT_OUTPUTTYPE_FILE, "png color", "demo.png");
        plot.plotting();
    }
```